# What can I do to get a test a HTML5 web site from my pc?

Tags: html

I downloaded the web site below using Firefox - then launched it on chrome - while it launches fine, it is not functional. Meaning the link below, will seek microphone permission and then actually record your voice - none are happening when I launch the way I did - what might be the fix?  Is there a tool available or a workaround?
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Update:
What I wanted was - is to make the two boxes small and move it to the bottom of the display - I was able to make it small but they are on the top right hand corner - how can I bring it down?

Comment: There's likely other files you are missing and back end services (accessed through AJAX and possibly tied to the site's URL) that would never be able to use.

Comment: Sorry nope - see below the answer.

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to find an answer to your problem, but what you're asking is different than what your solution was.  You don't provide us context that you're using any sort of web server - I thought you had downloaded the DOM of a page and were looking at that.  I would encourage you to be more explicit as to what you're doing in your environment so that others may see your question in a better light.

Answer (score 0):

If the page includes scripts such as jQuery, you would need to use CDN's for those in order for them to work.

You can see in your developer console what is not being loaded by pressing f12 or right click >> inspect element.

Comment: What is CDN's stan for?

Comment: CDN - content delivery network. you can find a whole lot of CDN's here - https://cdnjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be accessed as `http://` since `file://` does not get access to the microphone.  The Apache server running on a directory on a localhost machine is the way to go.